# Which Cassandra version is more stable for Production deployment? And which Cassandra driver is better?

Tags: cassandra, datastax

In My organisation we are planning to use Cassandra and these days we are running some experimental tests against Custom Configuraiton to check the better and stable verison of Cassandra. And we are using DataStax drivers.

We are running tests, INSERT into and Select * from CQL statements in very tight loop with higher load like 10K qps.

So any one has any experience on which Cassandra version is better and stable and which drivers shall be used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many organisations use latest, or nearly latest releases. 10k requests is rather low number of queries that a single node is capable of handling. This of course depends on your hardware, your data model, configuration, noisy neighbours applications etc. As a rule of thumb, latest release is usually better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot go wrong with the latest 2.0 release (2.0.9).  You can get that version from either the [Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) project or [DataStax](http://planetcassandra.org/cassandra/).  The Apache Cassandra [download page](http://cassandra.apache.org/download/) also has links for the latest release candidates (RC5 is the latest) of 2.1, but those are still in development, so consider that before installing them.

As for the driver, there are [drivers](http://planetcassandra.org/client-drivers-tools/) available for more than a dozen languages.  Chances are that you probably know or use one of them.  There is no one driver (at least that I am aware of) that significantly out-performs all of the others.  So pick the driver for the language that either:

1. You have the most thorough knowledge of.
2. Complies with the usage standards of your team.

For instance, you could make an argument for using Java.  After all, Cassandra is written in Java and all of the examples on the original DataStax Academy are done with the Java CQL Driver.  But that argument loses ground quickly if you have never done Java before.  Or if your team is a .Net shop, and there's nobody else who understands Java.  [InfoWorld's Andrew Oliver put it best](http://www.infoworld.com/d/application-development/ill-informed-haters-go-after-mongodb-205096?page=0,1) when he wrote:

> The lesson to be learned here is: Don't solve a simple problem with a
>   completely unfamiliar technology and apply it to use cases it isn't
>   especially appropriate for.

Again, you cannot go wrong with using a "DataStax Supported Driver" from their downloads page.

Comment: Thanks @BryceAtNetwork. Your answer certainly brought some clarity into my mind.

Answer (score 1):

“You should not deploy a Cassandra version X.Y.Z to production where Z <= 5.”

Source:

https://engineering.eventbrite.com/what-version-of-cassandra-should-i-run/

Hence go with 2.0.x . Currently its 2.0.10