# Choosing Apache Cassandra client

Tags: java, cassandra, nosql

There is a bunch of different cassandra's clients in now days. Most of them was built on top of Thrift driver and then adopted to use DataStax Java driver. I can name Kundera and Astynax as biggest of them. The last one has only a beta support for the Java driver. And there is an Achilles client that build on top of DataStax Java driver and supports all new Cassandra features. It's a little bit younger and I know nothing of it's use cases in production. But it looks very promising.

So I'm new in NoSQL world ask you to give me a hint - with client to use with new project? Suppose it will be a big solution with 33 nodes Cassandra cluster and a lot of different kinds of queries to db.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983190/cassandra-client-java-apis)? You could check out the list of possible drivers [here](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions).

Comment: @BuhakeSindi this question is almost two years old. Things change quickly and there is no talk about CQL and Thrift comparison for now (on my opinion). I saw the list of possible clients and chosen three of them. One modern and bright and two older and proven. But I still in doubts which one to use. It's a good sign to ask an advice.

Comment: Similar question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25155916/which-cassandra-version-is-more-stable-for-production-deployment-and-which-cass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the platform you're on has a client from DataStax, use that. The DataStax drivers for the jvm and .NET (and possibly others) are quite polished, support all available features, and deal with connection complexity internally very nicely. In addition, if you're looking to do Spark analytics, the DataStax Spark connector is the only option supporting good locality, and it uses the DataStax java driver internally.